# autocomplete menu not visible in jqgrid in a Bootstrap tab

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, jqgrid, jquery-autocomplete

JQuery 2.1.1, Bootstrap 3.0.3 and JQGrid 4.8.2

I have a jqgrid that is included on a page that utilizes Bootstrap tabs.  One of the columns uses autocomplete to provide options for inline editing.  The function fires and retrieves the data but the autocomplete menu is not visible.  If I run my code outside of the Bootstrap tab, the menu appears correctly.  I've tried playing around with the z-index of ui-autocomplete and tab-pane but nothing has worked.  Any suggestions?

```
<style>
.ui-autocomplete { font-size: 11px; position: absolute; cursor: default;z-index:1000 !important;}
</style>
```

Here is a snippet grid definition:

```
var myGrid =  jQuery("#payments").jqGrid({
           datatype: "local",
            data: myData,
            editurl: 'clientArray',
            onSelectRow: editRow,
            colModel: [
               { label: 'Payment ID', name: 'PaymentID', key: true, width: 75 },
               { label: 'Country', name: 'Country', 
                    width: 100 ,
                    editable: true,
                    edittype: "text",
                    editoptions: {
                        dataInit: function (element) {
                            window.setTimeout(function () {
                                $(element).autocomplete({
                                    id: 'AutoComplete',
                                    source: ["United States of America", "Germany", "Sweden", "Greece" ],
                                    minLength: 2,
                                    autoFocus: true
                                });
                            }, 100);
                        }
                    }
                },
                ....
            ],
            viewrecords: true,
            width: 1000,
            height: 250,
            subGrid: true, 
            subGridRowExpanded: showChildGrid, 
            pager: jQuery('#report_pager')
        });
```

This is a the tab that contains the grid:

```
...
<div class="tab-pane" id="spendT">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
       <fieldset class="well the-fieldset" >
          <legend class="the-legend">Spend</legend>
          <br>
          <div class="report_Tbl" id="report_Tbl"  style="text-align:left;padding:2px;">
             <div id="report_pager" class="scroll"  style="text-align:left;">    </div>
            <table id="payments" class="scroll" ></table>
         </div>
       </fieldset>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: I tried the code with [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) 4.9.1 and can't reproduce the problem. Could you try to change (temporary) URLs like described in [the wiki](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs) and verify whether the problem exist in free jqGrid? Could you provide the demo which reproduces the problem?

Comment: It turned out to be a problem with the jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js file I was including on the page.  I don't need the file for this particular page so I removed it.  Autocomplete is working now so I'll consider this one resolved.

Comment: Sorry, but one can use **only one** jQuery UI version on one page. I mean you can use for example either `jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js` or `jquery-ui-1.11.4.custom.min.js` for example on one page but not both. In any way, it's good that the problem is solved now.